# Conditional useEffect in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am developing a form with some number fields. The requirement is that some of the forms require special handling, for example: Volume will not be a user input but a product of surface area and height.

Currently Im using a useEffect Hook to capture the changes in surface area and height then update the disabled input field for Volume. I am trying to make the template generic so it could apply to other forms in the code. However, each of these templates shall have a distinct useEffect Hook since they are capturing different updates and responding in different way. Long story short, how do I dynamically|conditionally add useEffect to a functional component?

```
function Node(props: {
  nodeInfo: NodeInfo;
  // to return the state to the parent component
  submitNode: (nodeInfo: NodeInfo) => void;
}) {
  // mapping state to props
  const [nodeInfo, setNodeInfo] = useState(props.nodeInfo);

  // customize useEffect for each nodetype
  useEffect(() => {
    setNodeInfo({ ...nodeInfo, 'Volume (m^3)': nodeInfo['Area (m^2)'] * nodeInfo['Height (m)']});
  }, [nodeInfo['Area (m^2)', nodeInfo['Height (m)']]);

  const updateInfo = (paramName: string, value: number) => {
    setNodeInfo({ ...nodeInfo, [paramName]: value });
  };

  const validateInput = (paramName: string, value: number) => {
    const bounds = nodeBounds.find((nodeBound) => nodeBound.paramName === paramName);
    // no bounds found for validation
    if (bounds === undefined) return;

    if (value < bounds.minVal) {
      updateInfo(paramName, bounds.minVal);
      alert(
        bounds.errMsg ||
          `Input ${value} < ${bounds.minVal} is considered out of bound`,
      );
    } else if (value > (bounds.maxVal || 10000000)) {
      updateInfo(paramName, bounds.maxVal || 10000000);
      alert(
        bounds.errMsg ||
          `Input ${value} > ${
            bounds.maxVal || 10000000
          } is considered out of bound`,
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {Object.keys(nodeInfo).map((key) => {
        return (
          <SingleInput
            key={`input-${key}`}
            inputType="number"
            inputName={key}
            inputValue={nodeInfo[key as keyof NodeInfo]}
            updateInfo={(val: number) => updateInfo(key, val)}
            validateInput={(val: number) => validateInput(key, val)}
            disabled={disableList.includes(key)}
          />
        );
      })}
      <input type="button" value="submit" onClick={() => props.submitNode(nodeInfo)} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Write a function inside UseEffect and check condition inside it. Also for the forms I suggest you to use any form library. Because it'll be hard to maintain in the long run.